# MATLAB : Obtain a matrix by adding its last lines to the first lines of the basic matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

I have a matrix `B` and I would like to obtain a new matrix `C` from `B` by adding its last `w*a` rows to the first `w*a` rows (`w` and `a` will be defined afterwards).

My matrix `B` is generally defined by :

[image]

I would like to obtain matrix `C` defined in a general way by:
[image]

The characteristics of matrices `B` and `C` are:

- `L` and `w` are defined real values;
- `B0`,`B1`,...,`Bw` are of dimension: `a` by `b`;
- `B` is of dimension: `[(L+w)×a]` by `(L×b)`;
- `C` is of dimension: `(L×a)` by `(L×b)`.

**Example**: For `L = 4` and `w = 2` I obtain the following matrix `B`:
[image]

The `w*a = 2*1 = 2` last rows of `B` are:

[image]

The `w*a = 2*1 = 2` first rows of `B` are:

[image]

By adding the two matrices we have:

[image]

The matrix `C` thus obtained is then:
[image]

For `B0 = [1 0]`, `B1 = [0 1]` and `B2 = [1 1]`. We obtain :

- `B0`, `B1` and `B2` are of dimension `a` by `b` i.e. `1` by `2`;
- `B` is of dimension: `[(L+w )×(a)]` by `(L×b)` i.e. `[(4+2)×1]` by `(4×2)` i.e. `6` by `8`;
- `C` is of dimension: `(L×a)` by `(L×b)` i.e. `(4×1)` by `(4×2)` i.e. `4` by `8`.

The matrices `B` and `C` that I get are as follows:

[image]
[image]

```
B = 

    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0
    1    1    0    1    1    0    0    0
    0    0    1    1    0    1    1    0
    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    1
    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1

C = 

    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    1
    0    1    1    0    0    0    1    1 
    1    1    0    1    1    0    0    0
    0    0    1    1    0    1    1    0
```

I would like to have some suggestions on how to program this construction so that from a given matrix `B` I can deduce the matrix `C`.

Comment: Just slice your matrix B in two parts and add the second part to the corresponding line of the first part. Your question is a bit over-complicated I guess.

Comment: Okay, noted. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the matrices [as tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support). Consider [these reason and guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) on why you should include images in this case.

Comment: Okay @bad_coder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab's [range indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/array-indexing.html) should help you do this in a few steps. The key things to remember are that ranges are inclusive, i.e. `A[1:3]` is a three 3x1 matrix, and that you can use the keyword `end` to automatically index the end of the matrix row or column.

```
%% Variables from OP example

w = 2;
L = 4;

B0 = [1 0];
B1 = [0 1];
B2 = [1 1];
[a, b] = size(B0);

% Construct B
BX = [B0;B1;B2]
B = zeros((L+w)*a, L*b);
for ii = 0:L-1
   B(ii+1:ii+w+1, ii*b+1:ii*b+b) = BX;
end

%% Construct C <- THIS PART IS THE ANSWER TO THE QUESTION

% Grab first rows of B
B_first = B(1:end-w*a, :) % Indexing starts at first row, continues to w*a rows before the end, and gets all columns
% Grab last rows of B
B_last = B(end-w*a+1:end, :); % Indexing starts at w*a rows before the end, continues to end. Plus one is needed to avoid off by one error. 
% Initialize C to be the same as B_first
C = B_first;
% Add B_last to the first rows of C
C(1:w*a, :) = C(1:w*a, :) + B_last;
```

I get the output

```
C =

     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     1
     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     1
     1     1     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     1     1     0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Cecilia. It answers my question well. But just a remark: at the level of the construction of the matrix `B`, the loop for varied from `0` to `L-1` and not from `0` to `L` (in this case we obtain a matrix `B` of dimension `7` by `10` instead of `6` by `8` and a matrix `C` of dimension `5` by `10` instead of `4` by `8`).

Comment: Doh! And I even said to watch for inclusive ranges! It's one of the idiosyncrasies of Matlab that always gets me.

Comment: Ok thank you @Cecilia.